# Cannot get the custom notification when application is in background or closed FCM application

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When the app is in background or closed and notification arrives then the default notification comes and doesn't run my code of `onMessageReceived()`. I try many solution but the same problems.

Comment: Did you send a notification message or a data message?

Comment: i send the notification message and in the data i have an object Message (mY application is a chat application)     {   notification:{body, title,..........} ,data:{objectMessage}}

Comment: If you send a notification-message (or notification message with a data payload) then onMessageReceived is only called when the app is in the foreground.